# Unable to see variable's value in Razor under debug mode in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: debugging, razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am having a problem with seeing variable's value inside .cshtml page in Visual Studio 2015 RC under debug mode. I think that it may be a bug.

Hovering over a variable gives me just a tooltip describing variable's type and namespace to which it belongs. The only way I can see variable's value now is by adding it to watch list.

[image]

BTW I am runnig my code under Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview and below is screenshot of About page of Visual Stuio that I am using.

[image]

Any suggestions what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago with the RTM version of VS2015. I was able to solve it by performing the following steps:

1. Rename the corresponding CSHTML file
2. Create a new file with the same name as the previous CSHTML file.
3. Copy over the contents from the previous file.

However, today ihad the same issue and i did some more digging. I tracked it down to a code block in the CSHTML file at where i defined some string constants:

```
const string value = "abc";
```

When i just remove the `const` keyword, it works fine:

```
string value = "abc";
```

This is not a real solution but i hope it helps others who face the same problem